# How to handle DMLs properly in local MS Access Tables/database with VBA

Tags: vba, ms-access, transactions, ms-access-2007, dao

I'm trying to build a small application with VBA and forms on Access and I would like to make it somewhat failureproof.

I've been playing around with DAO objects and its members the simple way: literal string DMLs, `.OpenRecordset` method, looping through the returned rows, `.Edit` and `.Update`, et cetera. But looking around the net I found forum posts and guides that make use of `DBEngine.Workspaces` and its transaction methods and also `.QueryDefs` instead of `.Execute` for stored queries (either way just a select, insert or update).

My intention is just to manipulate the tables contained in the already open Access database itself. No external resources, whatever they might be like Oracle, MySQL or another Access file, and be able to rollback in case of failure, avoiding to insert invalid data.

Is all that really needed to achieve it? And if it is important, what's the best way to do it/where could I find complete and well explained reference material?

Comment: Use the `dbFailOnError` option of the `Execute` method. In case of an error, any changes are rolled back and a VBA runtime error is raised (you need to have error handling in the calling method). For simple select queries, you don't need any of the above, just regular error handling in VBA to close the recordset etc.

Comment: @KostasK. , understood! Much easier and simpler. Thank you so much for your help.

Edit: Does that advice aaply also for `UPDATE`, `INSERT` and `DELETE` operations? Thanks in advice for the next answer.

Comment: Yes, these are action queries and the `Execute` method can only run action queries.

Comment: By the way, the workspace is needed when you need to insert a record, grab the new ID and link it to a record in another table. Plenty of examples how to do that, it's not anything new.

Comment: Ah, okay! Thanks a lot for everything. I'm going to check that out right now.